# Extract part of array

Tags: arrays, excel, extract, openoffice-calc

I want to extract some part of array. Last six elements and first three. How can I do that in Excel and OpenOffice Calc?

1. Array that I have: 04:52    08:48   04:59   08:48   05:50   00:00   00:00
2. I need #1: 08:48    04:59   08:48   05:50   00:00   00:00
3. I need #2: 04:52   08:48   04:59

Copy of part of a comment:

*What I want is to count sum of 7 (AC75 shows it) of AB63:AH63 last elements (don't make it serious that it has 7 elements at all, it will have different numbers)*:

[image: SO28433287 question example]

Comment: please check [Excel vocabulary to find solutions faster](http://superuser.com/q/860919/118860). where does the array come from, what array formula creates it and why can't it return a different array, the one you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you extract a subarray from an array in a worksheet function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7815124/1176601)

Answer (score 0):

This may be easy in Excel because you have specified the positions of the elements you require. For example in ColumnB and copied across to ColumnG:

```
=CHOOSE(COLUMN(),"04:52","08:48","04:59","08:48","05:50","00:00","00:00")
```

and in ColumnA and copied across to ColumnC.

Alternatively, if your array is in A1:A7, in B1:

```
=IF(ROW()>1,$A1,"")
```

and in C1:

```
=IF(ROW()<4,$A1,"")
```

both copied down and formatted to suit.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out.. All variants shows Err, maybe it's my fault. Here is my table for clearly view. What I want is to count sum of  7 (AC75 shows it) of AB63:AH63 last elements (don't make it serious that it has 7 elements at all, it will have different numbers).
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-htWvWj3LItA/VNsku4j8MLI/AAAAAAAAAww/RHaBitJMg3w/w1244-h482-no/time.PNG

Comment: Ok. The table consists of days of week (horisontally) and 8 different weeks. The AC75 is the number of holiday days. So for example I want to take 12 days of holiday from 1st week of tuesday (means "antradienis" in the title. Then I should count sum of these cells: AC63:AH63 and AB64:AG64.

Comment: So I wanted to make other table with sums (from the day you take holidays using AC75 number and from the second table choose minimal sum. That's why I need to take from array last elements, cause then I'm taking holidays from tuesday, it means that it's left 6 days of first week (6 last elements) and 6 from second week (6 fist elements of second array). If AC75 is 20 then I neew to take 6 last elements from 1st week, 7 first from 2nd, and 7 from 3rd