# How to extract a sub array from a larger array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

From this 2-dimensional array in Excel {(43.0,37.5)(43.0,40.25)(43.0,40.5)(44.25,36.75)(44.25 ,38.75)(44.25,41.75)}

I want to extract an array with the value in the first column equals to 43.0
{(43.0,37.5)(43.0,40.25)(43.0,40.5)}

If anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: Did you look here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815124/how-do-you-extract-a-subarray-from-an-array-in-a-worksheet-function/10000636